# jQuery clone form field group add wp_editor() function to the textarea

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wp-editor

In CPT metabox I am using `wp_editor()`. The first one is loading through php function. However, when I clone the form fields via jQuery, it doesn't add wp_editor but simple textarea.

So [here](https://github.com/anteprimorac/js-wp-editor) I found a [script](https://github.com/anteprimorac/js-wp-editor) which loads wp_editor through javascript. However, when I tried to clone/append the form fields it doesn't load the wp_editor but simple textarea.

I believe that DOM doesn't loads the `wp_editor()` js function. So can anyone tell me how I can load wp_editor for cloned fields?

## jQuery

```
// Just to cross check. This is loading wp_editor on page load
jQuery('.cn-wp-editor').wp_editor();

// wp_localization
var title = cn_fields.title;
var teditor = cn_fields.editor;

// adding incremental id
var i = 1;

// clone fields
$('#add_item').on('click', function () {
    i++;
    $('#fieldgroup').append('<div class="formgroup"><div class="card-meta-box"><label for="card_title" class="card-field-label">Item Title</label><input type="text" name="' + title + '[]" id="' + title + i +'"></div><div class="card-meta-box"><textarea name="' + teditor + '[]" id="' + teditor + i +'" class="cn-wp-editor"></textarea></div><button class="remove">x</button></div><!-- formgroup -->');
    return false; //prevent form submission
});

// remove fields
$('#fieldgroup').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false; //prevent form submission
    i--;
});
```

Comment: hello, can you tell me, how to work with html part?

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44305061/1053190 by Raunak Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to reinitialized `wp_editor()` whenever you duplicate/copy
>   the field. Your code is not working as the copied/created field in not
>   in DOM on page load so `wp_editor()` was not getting attached to those
>   new field(s).

Check this code:

```
$('#add_item').on('click', function () {
    i++;
    $('#fieldgroup').append('<div class="formgroup"><div class="card-meta-box"><label for="card_title" class="card-field-label">Item Title</label><input type="text" name="' + title + '[]" id="' + title + i + '"></div><div class="card-meta-box"><textarea name="' + teditor + '[]" id="' + teditor + i + '" class="cn-wp-editor"></textarea></div><button class="remove">x</button></div><!-- formgroup -->');
    $('#' + title + i).wp_editor(); //<------ add this line
    return false; //prevent form submission
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: $(...).wp_editor is not a function can you help to fix this